# Repair broken ext4 partition with wrong superblock checksum

Tags: boot, partitioning, data-recovery, ext4

A few weeks ago I gave my laptop to the service to replace the keyboard.
There were two operating systems on the computer: windows 10 and linux (ubuntu 20.04).
The folder /home of my Ubuntu system was moved to a separate partition on the disk.
After the computer returned from the service, the partition /home stopped mounting due to problems with the superblock.

[TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), when trying to determine the backup superblocks, outputs the following:

> Linux file systems. data 570617856 975675391 405057536 superblock 0,
> block size=4096 [] To restore the file system using an alternative
> superblock, run fsck.ext4 -p -b superblock is a B block size device.

When i try use fsck it returns:

> fsck.ext4: superblock checksum does not match superblock when trying
> to open /dev/sda8 /dev/sda8: The super block could not be read or does
> not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 FS. If the device is valid and it
> does contain ext2/ext3/ext4 FS (and do not exchange, or us, or
> something else), then the super block is damaged, and you can try to
> run e2fsck with an alternative superblock: e2fsck -b 8193  or
> e2fsck -b 32768

I found other backup superblocks with "mke2fs -n /dev/xxx":

> Superblock backups stored on blocks: 32768, 98304, 163840, 229376,
> 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 4096000, 7962624, 11239424,
> 20480000, 23887872

But unfortunately i got the same result with each of them.

However, when I try to list the contents of the partition using TestDisk, it displays all the files and folders and I even could copy them.

So I can't understand if testdisk displays the contents of the partition, why does fsck say that the superblock is corrupted?

Is there a way to repair the partition or i need to format it and paste copied by testdisk files?

Thank you!